# Load XML document into variable with different select methods

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to load an XML document on the fly and then perform queries on that variable.

The following works and enables me to output Dutch strings

```
<xsl:variable name="language" select="exslt:node-set(document('Dutch.xml'))" />

<xsl:value-of select="$language/Translations/SiteInformationPanel/Customer" />
```

However this requires me to know the document to load in advance, the document to load will be based off an element in the input XML, so I've tried declaring the variable as follows:

```
  <xsl:variable name="language">
    <!-- Also attempted with <xsl:value-of -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="exslt:node-set(document('Dutch.xml'))" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

However this give an error `To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function.`

So my question really is how can I make the 2nd method equivalent to the 1st so I can load a different document.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to pass an argument to the `document` function that comes from the input XML, e.g. given an input XML document like

```
<Input language="Dutch">
  ....
</Input>
```

you could set a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="language" select="document(concat(/Input/@language, '.xml'))" />
```

Note that you don't need the `node-set` function at all here, as `document` returns a node set directly.